# what is the different between (&t).value and t.value in golang? t is a struct

Tags: go, pointers, struct

I have such a struct in golang like below:

```
type test struct {
    value int
}
```

and when I tried this

```
t := test{1}
fmt.Println((&t).value)
fmt.Println(t.value)
```

the compiler did not report an error，and I got the same output of 1,
this output confused me.What is different between (&t).value and t.value in golang?

Comment: The syntax to acces a member of a struct or a member of a pointer to a struct is the same in golang. The compiler understands what you want and does the right thing in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector expression `p.f` where `p` is a pointer to some struct type and `f` is a field of that struct type is shorthand for `(*p).f`.

Your expression `(&t)` results in a value of the pointer type `*test`. So that makes `(&t).value` the shorthand for `(*(&t)).value`.

---

[Selectors](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Selectors):

> The following rules apply to selectors:
>
> 1. For a value `x` of type `T` or `*T` where `T` is not a pointer
>    or interface type, `x.f` denotes the field or method at the
>    shallowest depth in `T` where there is such an `f`. If there is not
>    exactly one `f` with shallowest depth, the selector expression is
>    illegal.
> 2. For a value `x` of type `I` where `I` is an interface type,
>    `x.f` denotes the actual method with name `f` of the dynamic value
>    of `x`. If there is no method with name `f` in the method set of
>    `I`, the selector expression is illegal.
> 3. **As an exception, if the type of `x` is a defined pointer type
>    and `(*x).f` is a valid selector expression denoting a field (but
>    not a method), `x.f` is shorthand for `(*x).f`.**
> 4. In all other cases, `x.f` is illegal.
> 5. If `x` is of pointer type and has the value nil and `x.f`
>    denotes a struct field, assigning to or evaluating `x.f` causes a
>    run-time panic.
> 6. If `x` is of interface type and has the value `nil`, calling or
>    evaluating the method `x.f` causes a run-time panic.